# boost exceptions

Tags: c++, boost, exception

Do all boost exceptions derive from std::exception?  If not do they all derive from some base exception class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/exception/doc/exception_exception_hpp.html) `boost::exception` doesn't inherit `std::exception`.

The [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/exception/doc/frequently_asked_questions.html) explains why.

However [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/exception/doc/exception_types_as_simple_semantic_tags.html) explains how to correctly use Boost exceptions.

Comment: Boost.Exception is a framework for storable and re-throwable exceptions. They're not thrown directly from any boost library. The FAQ http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/exception/doc/frequently_asked_questions.html explains why `boost::exception` doesn't inherit from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 7):

A "good Boost citizen" library should throw using `boost::throw_exception`, in order to support configurations where exception handling is disabled.

The `boost::throw_exception` function requires that the type of the passed exception derives publicly from `std::exception` (as of version 1.37.0 or thereabouts `boost::throw_exception` will issue a compile error if that requirement is not met.) In addition and by default, exceptions emitted using `boost::throw_exception` derive from `boost::exception`.

However, there is no requirement for Boost libraries to throw exceptions through `boost:throw_exception` or to derive from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. Can't think of a boost library throwing something non-std::exception based.